# Cloud-init Empty User-data

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init, user-data

## Problem

I have been trying (and failing) to get Ubuntu 20.04 to autoinstall. It keeps going through most of the process, but when I try to access the SeedFile `s=http://myip:port/file` it will successfully access the file (according to my webserver logs `/var/log/httpd/access_log`, but then when I try and view the user-data file in my installer shell its blank.

When I check my cloud-init logs `/var/log/cloud-init.log` it shows a few peculiar errors. But I can't figure out how to resolve them.

```
util.py[DEBUG]: Read 0 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud/user-data
...
util.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to load yaml from string of length 0 with allowed root types
...
util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceNoCloud.DataSourceNoCloudNet'> failed
```

Note: not necessarily in order of appearance.

## Making my ask

Can anyone explain why the `cloud-init` process isn't successfully loading/writing my `user-data` file?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

So I'm not entirely sure why the `user-data` file is empty as seen from the installer. My guess is that the `cloud-init` program is cutting content from it rather then copying it out. But I can't say for sure. NOW the solution to the problem that lead me to ask this, was **READ THE !@#$!@ CLOUD-INIT** [**FAQs**](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html#how-can-i-debug-my-user-data)!!!

Basically all I had to do to stop my cloud-init from failing back to the default install DataSource, was to properly configure my `user-data` file by making sure the first line of the file contained ONLY `#cloud-config`

I know this doesn't actually answer the question "why is my `user-data` empty" but it solved my problem so I consider it the answer. :)